# How with one model dbt update data in another table (in another schema)?

Tags: dbt

The task is this: I have several models and after each processing of the model I would like to increase the count of processing by 1 in a separate table (always containing 1 row). Please give me a hint on how best doing it.

I think this is a job for post_hook but I'd like a concrete example.

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise and tell us when should you increase the count by 1?

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't seem like a great idea. Why do you need this? DBT works quite hard to be idempotent (i.e. same result if you run it once, or more than once in quick succession). Moreover, incrementing requires you to read the existing table and overwrite it with the result: a circular reference.